# Maven annotation processing during test-compile phase rather than compile phase?

Tags: maven, annotations

I've written a simple java annotation processor that generates a java file and a resources file.

I've packaged the annotation processor into a jar file, and my maven project can load it and process annotations during the **compile** phase of the maven lifecycle. The generated code appears in *target/generated-sources/annotations* and the generated resource file in *target/classes* as expected.

However I only want to use the generated java file and resource file during testing, so I'd like the generated files to appear in *target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations* and *target/test-classes* respectively. In short, I need the annotation processing to happen in the **test-compile** phase rather than the **compile** phase.

More to the point: the annotation processor runs over the production code, but generates files that are then included in *target\foo-test.jar*, not *target\foo.jar*.

I'm not sure how to do this with maven, except maybe moving the generated files during the **process-test-resources** phase, which seems like an ugly hack.

Any suggestions?

edit: I tried added `<scope>test</scope>` to the dependency on the annotation processor, and I can see that the processor is created during the **testCompile** phase, but the the processor's `process()` method is not invoked, and nothing happens.

**Edit #1**: the annotation processor contains the following code to write a .java file and a resouce file under *META-INF/services* :

```
@Override
public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
  List<String> declarations = generateDeclarationsForAnnotation(roundEnv);
  generateServiceImplFile(declarations);
  generateResourceFile();
  return true;
}

private void generateResourceFile() throws Exception {
  JavaFileManager.Location location = StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT;
  FileObject file= processingEnv.getFiler().createResource(location,
    "", "META-INF/services/x.y.z.FooService");
  BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(file.openWriter());
  ... write resource file ...
}

private void generateServiceImplFile(List<String> declarations) throws Exception {
  JavaFileObject file = processingEnv.getFiler().createSourceFile("x.y.z.FooServiceImpl");
  BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(file.openWriter());
  ... write source code ...
}
```

I currently declare the dependencies in the `pom.xml` file as follows:

```
<!-- Dependency for the @Foo annotation -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>x.y.z</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo-annotations</artifactId>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- Dependency for the @Foo annotation processor -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>x.y.z</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo-annotations-processor</artifactId>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

I'm using JDK 1.7, the `maven-compiler-plugin` version 3.1. The annotation processor is invoked by virtue of it existing on the classpath. I have not added any processor plugins, etc, or tweaked the compiler plugin, etc to get this working.

**Edit #2**: I made the following change to the `maven-compiler-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
  <executions>
    <!-- Disable annotation processing for default compile execution -->
    <execution>
      <id>default-compile</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <proc>none</proc>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <!-- Only annotation process in this execution, with generated code 
         going to generated-test-sources directory. -->
    <execution>
      <id>compile-with-annotations-processor</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <proc>only</proc>
        <generatedSourcesDirectory>
          ${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources/test-annotations
        </generatedSourcesDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

This disables annotation processing for the `default-compile` execution, and the `compile-with-annotations-processing` execution does annotation processing only, putting the generated source into *target\generated-test-sources\test-annotations* directory.

When I run this I see the generated java file in the *target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations* directory, although the resource file still appears in the *target/classes* directory. I'm guessing that I can fix that by changing the `generateResourceFile()` method to use `StandardLocation.SOURCE_OUTPUT` instead of `StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT`.

Also, this fix does not handle multiple annotation processors elegantly. I really only want this one particular annotation processor disabled during the `default-compile` execution, and only that processor enabled (with different source directories) in the `compile-with-annotations-processing` execution. Otherwise, if I add another (unrelated) annotation processor, it's generated code will not appear in the expected place.

**Edit #3**: Maybe a simpler solution would be to allow the compiler to run the annotation processor as normal, and then move the generated files from *target\generated-sources* to *target\generated-test-sources*, using the `maven-antrun-plugin`, for example.

**Edit #4**: I think I have solved this issue, using the `maven-antrun-plugin` as mentioned above:

- configure `maven-antrun-plugin` to move files from *target/generated-sources/annotations* to *target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations*, and from *target/classes/META-INF/services* to *target/test-classes/META-INF/services*, during the **compile** phase.
- configure `build-helper-maven-plugin` to add *target/generated-test-sources* to the **generate-test-sources** phase.

My *foo.jar* and *foo-test.jar* seem to be constructed correctly :-)

**Edit #5**: I discovered a plugin called `maven-processor-plugin`, and I've configured it to run at **generate-test-sources** phase over the production code, and set the output directories to *target/generated-test-sources/annotations* and *target/test-classes*. Works like a charm. So there's no need for the `maven_antrun_plugin` at all now.

Comment: You need to change your plugin in the way to put the generated code into the appropriate folder and of course bound it to a different phase...May be you can show the full code of your plugin so we can give more details hints how to go...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've added example code to show how the code is generated by the annotation processor, and details of the maven setup. Not sure which plugin you are referring to when you say "change your plugin" ?

Answer (score 2):

I discovered a plugin called `maven-processor-plugin`, and I've configured it to run at `generate-test-sources` phase over the production code, and set the output directories to *target/generated-test-sources/annotations* and *target/test-classes*. Works like a charm. So there's no need for the `maven_antrun_plugin` at all now.

Another solution I came up with (because sometimes it may be better to use `maven-compiler-plugin` rather than `maven-processor-plugin`) is to generate the code using the annotation processor at `compile` phase, so that the code ends up in the usual *target/generated-sources/annotations* directory. The test code in the same module has access to this location, and tests run fine. Then I configured the `maven-jar-plugin` to exclude the generated code from the *`artifactId`.jar* and include the generated code in a new artifact called *`artifactId`-test-libs.jar*. Other modules then add a test dependency on *`artifactId`-test-libs*.

Answer (score 2):

Since maven-compiler-plugin 3.5 you can configure the annotation processors with `annotationProcessorPaths`. You can then apply this configuration to the default test-compile execution:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <configuration>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>x.y.z</groupId>
                        <artifactId>foo-annotations-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>a.b.c</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```